# Adding new item to pageCollection's object

Tags: silverlight, pagination

i am working with an pageCollectionin silverlight ,i have some remove and addition work in  to the pagedviewcollection's  object

i was able to remove from collection as below

```
_pageCollection.RemoveAt(_index);
```

but i am not able add an item to the pageCollection .how to   add an  item to the _pageCollection. i feel it should be dealt with below code

```
_pageCollection.AddNew();
```

but i amnot able to get how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a PagedCollectionView you have to set a source IEnumerable. If you add it to this collection it will work (assuming that your PCV is working with a list of Products which have an id).

```
myPagedCollectionView = new PagedCollectionView(myCollection);
myCollection.Add(new Product(){Id=5});
```

If you work with AddNew you have to do it like this :

```
var obj = (Product)myPagedCollectionView.AddNew();

obj.Id = 5;
```

Hope this is what you needed.